# UITableView hangs for 5 seconds between heightForRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I have an extremely weird behavior here. I'm using RSSKit to download and parse an XML-Feed. So far so good. That happens during a few milliseconds. After thats done I call reloadData on my TableView. Immediately thereafter the numberOfRowsInSection and heightForRowAtIndexPath calles in. Then there is nothing happening for about 5 seconds. Only after that 5 seconds cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called.

And it gets even more weird! During this period when nothing is happening, the tableView is already completely responsive. When interacting with the UI cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called immediately.

Placing a setNeedsDisplay on the tableview directly after the reloadData doesn't change anything. I assume this issue seems to be connected to the Window-Server of iOS?

A small summary how it appears to me for now: The update process of the UI seems to not react for about 5 seconds while the phone is doing nothing.

Anyone any idea how this could be tracked to a cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Fail! dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() ... back into the main thread and everything works fine ...